# Downloading files in place similar to github

Tags: downloads

I don't know if I should ask this here but I didn't know where to ask it. Just wanted to download some files that recalls me to the github repositories for the source code so maybe there is a similar way to download them. I just want to download [this files](http://www.intoxitones.com/mtg_render/) without doing it one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on Ubuntu, use `wget`:

```
wget -r -nH -np http://www.intoxitones.com/mtg_render/
```

- `-r` - Download recursively
- `-nH` - Do not create a directory for the hostname (`www.intoxitones.com`)
- `-np` - Do not ascend to a parent
  directory

This will create a few files named `index.html` with some garbage affixed to it, which you can manually delete.

Comment: Thanks. And how would I use wget for some links like this? http://media-dominaria.cursecdn.com/attachments/51/540/635032484133466487.jpg   http://media-dominaria.cursecdn.com/attachments/51/460/635032484118803521.gif  I tried with wget -r http://media-dominaria.cursecdn.com/attachments/51/

Comment: @Arturo that would be more difficult, since the site doesn't allow directory listing. You'll have to find a page which links to those files and try to download that page recursively.